# Backgrid:render isn't being called

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backgrid, backbone-layout-manager

Backgrid is rendering

```
<table class="backgrid"></table>
```

but nothing else. Breakpoints in Backgrid:render() are not reached. I'm a Backbone newbie adapting someone else's code and so am not sure exactly what should be happening but LayoutManager:render() is called..it just never seems to get to Backgrid... The data I want to display are being fetched and look as if they are in the right format...but have to admit that it's difficult to tell once they've been wrapped up in a Backbone collection. Any pointers for how to debug/why Backgrid's render is not being called gratefully received.

Code below:

ListenView.js

```
define([
    'backbone',
        'underscore',
        'backgrid',
    'app/models/PersonModel',
    'app/collections/PersonCollection',
    'app/views/PersonListView',
    'hbs!app/templates/listen_template'
    ],
    function(
    Backbone,
        _,
        Backgrid,
        Person,
    PersonCollection,
    PersonListView,
    listenTemplate
    ) {

    App = window.App || {};
    var ListenView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: listenTemplate,
        initialize: function(params) {
            //fetch the list of seen people
            this.model.attributes.seenPeople.fetch( {
                success: function(coll, resp) {
                    //console.log(coll);
                }
            });
        },
        afterRender: function() {
            //initialise person view
        console.log("creating Backgrid");
        this.seenPeopleView = new Backgrid.Grid({
                        columns: [{
                                name: "email",
                                label: "Email",
                                cell: "string"  
                        },{
                                name: "id",
                                label: "ID",
                                cell: "integer"  
                        }, {
                                name: "title",
                                label: "Title",
                                cell: "string" }
                        ],
                        collection: this.model.attributes.seenPeople
                    });
            this.seenPeopleView.render();
                $('#seen-people-list').append(this.seenPeopleView.el);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the success method from the fetch you should call afterRender.

```
 var self=this;
 this.model.attributes.seenPeople.fetch( {
     success: function(coll, resp) {
                self.afterRender();
            }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Suleap and sorry, only just seen this. I've just given it a go but it still just renders an empty <table class="backgrid"></table>... Any other things to try/debug? In the meantime, I've got it working with bbGrid, suggesting the data is coming through fine, but bbGrid is much less full-featured than Backgrid so I'd love to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating backgrid instance in view (this.seenPeopleView) create instance as

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({...<your columns and collection related code>..});
```

Then Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document as

```
$('#seen-people-list').append(grid.render().el);
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: Thanks @Mazzu but still just the empty <table class="backgrid"></table> and still not reaching the breakpoints in backgrid.js render (line 2849) - I think there must be some reason why it's not calling that.

Comment: Also one more thing, put your code from "afterRender" to "render" function. Because "render" function gets called when view is initialized.

Comment: Thanks again @Mazzu but no errors in console - that's what's so confusing. When I created a render: function(){} and put it in there, I didn't even get the empty Backgrid table...

Comment: can you share some link? probably jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: Just pointed the guy whose code I'm adapting to this threat and he's told me that, because it's using LayoutManager 'overriding render doesn’t work, as that it what calls serialize(), feeds the result to the template, and puts the output inside the views element'. I've just tried his suggestion of adding 'this.listenTo(this.model.attributes.seenPeople, 'change', this.seenPeopleView.render());' to initialize() to see if Backgrid wasn't rendering if there was no data in this.model.attributes.seenPeople but same thing happening - just an empty table. I'll see if I can get the code somewhere - thx

Comment: Sure take your time :) And share the link, I will try to figure it out!